# PS Vita Internet Connection not connecting

Tags: ps-vita, networking

My PS Vita finds every network connection access points, but mine! How can this be fixed. It can't see mine at all. Even when I manually add my router to the access points list on my PS Vita, still does not connect! Why is that?

Comment: Is your router set to operate at 5ghz?  If so, change it to operate at 2.4ghz.  The Vita only operates at 2.4ghz for WLAN.

Answer (score -2):

If its a 5ghz router it won't find it. The vita runs on 2.4ghz. Hope that helps

Comment: taking a comment and posting it as answer is not very nice. At least provide some more information - like how to switch from 5 to 2.4gHz.